# child_process.spawn returns null on stdout.read

Tags: node.js

I execute a process in Node via [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). For some reason `stdout` and `stderr` is `null`. Is there any explanation what could go wrong here? I assume that `spawn` already started the process, correct?

```js
var p = require('child_process').spawn('ipconfig.exe', [], {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: {
        ...process.env
    },
    stdio: 'pipe'
});

var stdout = p.stdout.read(10);
console.log(stderr);

var stderr = p.stderr.read(10);
console.log(stderr);
```